# Javascript redirect window.location.url with .hash

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make redirect and pass # parameters

```
// I'm at: http://example.com/index.html
var url = 'http://example.com/category.html';
var hash = '#testsite';

// Ignores # and all after
window.location.href = url + hash;

// Does not work, sets hash first, then redirects to url without maintaining hash
window.location.href = url;
window.location.hash = hash;
```

Is it possible to redirect like that using javasript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is `templocation` but this works great:

```js
var url = 'http://example.com/category.html';
var hash = '#testsite';

window.location.href  = url + hash;
```

Comment: Just noticed, it is site that right after loading removes my #and after. Got to look into what it removes it... and I was tearing my hairs out for last hour why it wasn't working.

Comment: I mean, redirect is proper... but another script removes it from url right after page loads. So I didn't see it and assumed it was not being passed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like below

```
var url = 'http://example.com/category.html';
var hash = '#testsite';
window.open(url+"?hash="+hash,"_self");
//http://example.com/category.html?hash=#testsite
```

Comment: If I'm not wrong it would pass #testsite as query parameter. Right? That I don't want unfortuneatly.. Thx for your effort tho!